# Schwarz lemma, conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is analytic in the unit disk, with $|f| \leq 1$, $ f(0)=0$, and $f(r)=f(-r)$ for some $r\in (0,1)$. Then $$|f(z)| \leq |z||\frac{z^2-r^2}{1-r^2z^2}|$$

I know that we have $|f|\leq|z|$ by Schwartz lemma, and $ \frac{z^2-r^2}{1-r^2z^2}$ can be written as a product of two conformal mappings that map unit disk to unit disk, what we need to do is to show that $ |\frac{z^2-r^2}{1-r^2z^2}|$ is equal to one? How do we use the condition $f(-r)=f(r)$ for some $r \in (0,1)$?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Take $f(z)=z^2$, for instance. It is analytic in the unit disk, with $|f|\leqslant1$ there, and $f(0)=0$. Furthermore, $f\left(\frac12\right)=f\left(-\frac12\right)$. However, it is *not* true that$$|z|<1\Longrightarrow\bigl|f(z)\bigr|\leqslant|z|\left|\frac{z^2-\frac14}{1-\frac{z^2}4}\right|,$$since that would imply that $f\left(\pm\frac12\right)=0$, which does not happen.

Comment: Wow! excellent counter example!

Comment: @WLET What made you think that the statement was true?

Comment: This is a problem from previous preliminary exam.